# 100% Width CSS navbar menu

Tags: html, css, nav

I made a navbar but I can not make it full width.

Image preview: 
[image]

I'd like to have it full width and without padding, like this: 
[image]

```
#cssmenu {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #1CE678;

}
#cssmenu > ul {
  background: #3db2e1;

}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: right;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  -moz-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}
```

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
            <ul>
                <li><a href='#'>1</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>2</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>3</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>4</a></li>
                <li class='active'><a href='#'>5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: please share your html too

Comment: can we see your `HTML` please?

Comment: added html code

Comment: [CSS Reset](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=css+reset&kz=-1&kn=1&k1=-1&kk=-1&kak=-1&kao=-1&kae=d&ks=m&kd=1&t=hb&ia=web)

Answer (score 1):

make you margin padding 0

Html

```
 <div id=cssmenu >

  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

Css

```
body{
  margin:0;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #1CE678;
 margin:0;
  padding:0;

}

    #cssmenu > ul {
      background: #3db2e1;
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      text-align:right;

    }

    #cssmenu > ul > li {
      display:inline-block;

      -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
      -moz-perspective: 1000px;
      perspective: 1000px;
    }
```

Comment: check now i give you full code.hope it will help you

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove `body` margin:

```
body { margin: 0; }
```

Comment: @JvykiRazbalowski Be sure to mark the answer as [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it solved your problem, once the waiting period is over.

Answer (score 0):

The cause is most likely your `<ul>`. Modify your CSS like so:

```
#cssmenu > ul {
  background: #3db2e1;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;

}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: right;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  -moz-perspective: 1000px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

You'll also want to make sure that the parent element (presumably `body`) doesn't have any padding.

```
body {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to put this on every css files, I hope it will help

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply using 
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` inside of your html head? My personal website navbar file is very similar to yours but I haven't encountered this sort of issue.